# replaceAll "|" by "$" in java

Tags: java, replaceall

I have tried to replace all "|" by "2" using following code:

```
 String myString = "I want to change | with 2";
 String trimedString = myString.replaceAll("|", "2");
 System.out.print(trimedString);
```

My expected output was:

```
"I want to change | with 2"
```

But real output was:

```
"2I2 2w2a2n2t2 2t2o2 2c2h2a2n2g2e2 2|2 2w2i2t2h2 222"
```

It added 2 before and after each char. What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: The pipe character has to be escaped in a regular expression, try "\\|" instead of "|" .

Comment: `|` is a special character in regex so you need to escape it: `\|` (or `"\\|"` in java strings).

Comment: Btw your replacement and your expected output don't match. Assuming you fix the regex you'd get `"I want to change 2 with 2"`

Comment: It worked !!
Thanks @Thomas

Answer (score 6):

You have to insert two backslashes in front of the pipe-symbol in order to escape it.

```
String myString = "I want to change | with 2";
String trimedString = myString.replaceAll("\\|", "2");
System.out.print(trimedString);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you use `replaceAll`, the first argument is treated as a regular expression. Thus you need to escape the `|`, which is a regex metacharacter:

```
String trimedString = myString.replaceAll("\\|", "2")
```

Alternatively, you can use one of the `replace()` methods instead of `replaceAll()`. They still replace all occurrences, but don't use regex matching. For instance:

```
String trimedString = myString.replace("|", "2");
```

which treats each argument as a literal string. Or, since you are doing a single-character replacement, you can use:

```
String trimedString = myString.replace('|', '2');
```

which will be by far the most efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably yet another victim of naming used in *replace* methods in String class.

Most people introduced to these methods (based on difference in their names), think that `replaceAll(target,replacement)` and `replace(target,replacement)` are different in a way that `replace` will not replace all occurrences of target (since it doesn't have that `All` suffix). But that is not true, both methods will replace all targets.

Real difference between them is that:

- `replaceAll` is using regular expression (regex) syntax, and some characters are special there like your `|` so you would need to escape it first `"\\|"` (also `$` is special in replacement part so you would need to escape it there)
- `replace` uses literals.

So in your case you could simply use

```
String trimedString = myString.replace("|", "2");
```

---

So

- when you see `replaceAll` think of it as `replaceRegex`
- when you see `replaceFirst` thing of it as `replaceRegexOnce`
- when you see `replace` think of it as `replaceAllLiterals`.